# how to use a list containing the query result with hibernate and display it in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

In my servlet I construct the query like the following:

```
    net.sf.hibernate.Session s = null;
    net.sf.hibernate.Transaction tx;
    try {
        s= HibernateUtil.currentSession();
        tx=s.beginTransaction();
        Query query = s.createQuery("select  opcemployees.Nom,opcemployees.Prenom,dailytimesheet.TrackingDate,dailytimesheet.Activity," +
                "dailytimesheet.ProjectCode,dailytimesheet.WAName,dailytimesheet.TaskCode," +
                "dailytimesheet.TimeSpent,dailytimesheet.PercentTaskComplete from  Opcemployees opcemployees,Dailytimesheet dailytimesheet  " +
                "where opcemployees.Matricule=dailytimesheet.Matricule  and dailytimesheet.Etat=3 " +
                "group by opcemployees.Nom,opcemployees.Prenom" );  

        List opdts= query.list();
        request.setAttribute("items", opdts);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("EspaceValidation.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (HibernateException e){   e.printStackTrace();}
```

But in the jsp I can't display the result correctly. I do the following in JSP:

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td>${item}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

thanks for help.

Comment: the problem here is that i join 2 tables and i want to display results using jstl.
here it is a native sql query. the problem that the result is stored in a list. and in jsp i don't know how to manipulate this list.

Answer (score 3):

You need to determine the object type of every list item. It should be an existing model object (a Javabean like class with private properties and public getters). The `${item}` in JSP would only display its [`Object#toString()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) outcome, something like `com.packagename.ClassName@hashcode`. Or if the `toString()` method is overridden, then you would see a "human friendly" string. Other way to reveal the type would then be debugging the `getClass()` of the list item:

```
System.out.println(opdts.get(0).getClass().getName());
```

Once the type is known and the property names are known, then you can just access its properties in EL like `${item.someProperty}`, `${item.otherProperty}`, etcetera.

**Update**: since the list seems to contain `Object[]` as every item (thus the list signature is actually `List<Object[]>`), here's how you could display it in JSP/JSTL:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="objects">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach items="${objects}" var="object">
                <td>${object}</td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

This does basically the same as following in "raw" Java:

```
System.out.println("<table>");
for (Object[] objects : list) {
    System.out.println("<tr>");
    for (Object object : objects) {
        System.out.println("<td>" + object + "</td>");
    }
    System.out.println("</tr>");
}
System.out.println("</table>");
```

Comment: you mean that i could create a bean that bind the 2 classes here such as opcemployees and dailytimesheet

Comment: since joining the two tables(objects) don't let to display different property from different objects

Comment: What exactly does the returned list contain?

Comment: it contains column from first table called dailytimesheet and othersfrom the second table called opcemployees

Comment: so different columns(properties) from different tables(objects)

Comment: What object type exactly is it? What does `${item}` say? What result did you got in webpage? What does `getClass().getName()` say for every item? Do you understand my answer? Do you understand Java at any way? PS: you can edit comments within 5 minutes by clicking `edit` link at end of a comment.

Comment: [Ljava.lang.Object;@1f09a31  
[Ljava.lang.Object;@11b1d80 
this is what returns: System.out.println(opdts.get(0).getClass().getName());

Comment: yes it is ok i knew this conversion to Object[] from the start but this is not really the problem since i have only one record displayed or the query result must be 2 records.
I can't put the request dispatcherv in the loop and i can't have all the resultset.
so this is what i am doing:

Comment: `` for(Iterator it =query.iterate();it.hasNext();)
{ if(it.hasNext()){
Object[] obj = (Object[])it.next();
System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());

request.setAttribute("items",obj );
}

}
request.getRequestDispatcher("Validation.jsp").forward(request, response);


`

Comment: No... Just put list in request scope. Do not overwrite the request attribute with a single item everytime. That said... I don't mean to be harsh, but do you in any way *understand* what you're doing? It look more and more that you're just shooting in the dark. I stongly, strongly recommend to stop with this and go get a decent tutorial/book and learn the stuff. Learn basic Java. Learn Hibernate. Learn JSP/Servlet. Then continue. Do not stab around in the dark on an existing project. It's only a waste of time. You've been busy with this since half March and you don't seem to make any progress.